# Locally finiteness condition

Tags: general-topology

A collection $\mathscr{A}= \bigl\lbrace A_i \bigr\rbrace_{i\in I}$ of subsets of a topological space $S$ is said to be *locally finite* if every $x\in S$ has a neighborhood $U_x$ that intersects only finitely many of the $A_i$’s. In other words, every $x\in S$ has a neighborhood $U_x$ such that the set 
\begin{align*}
\bigl\lbrace i\,|\, U_x \cap A_i \neq \emptyset \bigr\rbrace
\end{align*}
is finite.

I want to prove that If $\mathscr{A}$ is locally finite, then every $x\in S$ is contained only in finitely many of the $A_i$’s. Here is my trial: If $\mathscr{A}$ is locally finite, then every $x\in S$ has a neighborhood $U_x$ that intersects only finitely many of the $A_i$’s. Then, the collection $\bigl\lbrace U_x \bigr\rbrace_{x\in S}$ is an open cover of $S$. For any $y\in S$, $y$ is contained in some $U_x$. Since $U_x$ intersects only finitely many of the $A_i$’s, then $y$ either contained in none of the $A_i$’s or contained in finitely many of the $A_i$’s.

What should I do for the first possibility? Can it be rejected? If not, some points of S may not be in any of the $A_i$’s. Am I right ?

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: your proof is correct

Comment: BTW . A useful general result is that if $A$ is a locally finite family of closed subsets then $\cup A$ is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any $x\in S$. So there exists an open neighbourhood U of $x$ such that the familly $\{A_i:A_i\cap U\neq\emptyset\}$ is finite.So, by considering, if $x\in A_i$ then $x\in A_i\cap U$ we can write the following,

Then $\{A_i:x\in A_i\}\subset\{A_i:A_i\cap U\neq\emptyset\} $, we know the secon one is finite. Thus $\{A_i:x\in A_i\}$ is fnite.

Comment: My Question is: Can $x\in S$ not lie in any of the $A_i$’s ?

Comment: @Hussein Eid We took $x\in S$

Comment: I think finitely many implies that there are $0,1,2,\dots,n$ such sets, where $n$ is a natural number, so I do not think it is a matter, whether they are i.e. 5 or 3 or 0.

Comment: Does $x\in S$ imply that $x\in A_i$ for some $i$ ?  @S.S.Danyal

Comment: @Hussein Eid No it doesn't

Comment: @ Hussein Eid You want to see "every x∈S is contained only in finitely many of the Ai’s". So it means you want to see $\{A_i:x\in A_i\}$ is finite. Take any $A_{i_0}\in\{A_i:x\in A_i\}$, then $x\in A_{i_0} $,then $ x\in A_{i_0} \cap U$, then $A_{i_0}\cap U\neq\emptyset$, then $A_{i_0}\ in \{A_i:A_i\cap U\neq\emptyset\}$ , then $\{A_i:x\in A_i\}\subset\{A_i:A_i\cap U\neq\emptyset\}$

Comment: Any finite collection of subsets of $S$ is a locally finite family. A different kind of example is to let $S=\mathbb R$ and $A=\{[2n,2n+1]: n\in \mathbb Z\}$.